# Python - Using Google Calendar API

Tags: python, calendar

i've got a little problem with google calendar api.

I want add event summary (and other options) using array:

```
event = {
                    'summary:': [temp_sheet[0]],
                    'start': {
                        'dateTime': '2017-07-28T19:00:00',
                        'timeZone': 'Europe/Warsaw',
                        },
                    'end': {
                        'dateTime': '2017-07-29T07:30:00',
                        'timeZone': 'Europe/Warsaw',
                        }
        }
```

`temp_sheet[0]` holds a some text and i want to put it to the summary. But after checking Calendar, there is 'There is no Summary'

Any Help ;>?

Thanks! (:

Comment: You surrounded your array call with square brackets, that means you're passing an array of length one when you should be passing a string.

Comment: Thanks, but im trying multiple ways to do that :P so brackets are a one of they

Answer (score 2):

There is a field of summary and decription of the event.

**OFFICIAL DOCUMENTATION**
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events

Comment: Thanks for Documentation link, so using:

str(temp_sheet[0]

Now it is string
But it didn't work :/

Comment: There is of course str(temp_sheet[0]) can't edit after 5 mins :C

Comment: Try using the API execution available at this webpage and add your parameters to check if its working.  https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert

Comment: Thanks, i will try it.